# Oscilator with Limited oscillation count

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, xilinx

I did implement below oscillator using cascaded not gates.
[image]
I want to know how can I change such circuit to oscillate only for limited number of oscillations?
e.g. I want designed circuit oscillate only for 15 times. Please note I'm going to implement this on FPGA so only digital elements are required.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that circuit can be designed and guaranteed to oscillate at a slow enough enough rate you can use it to clock the fabric flipflops.  Then just build a counter and use it to gate the EN signal.

I'd be very wary though, I'm not sure how you could guarantee that you wouldn't see runt pulses very occasionally at startup or shutdown which may be seen by your counter but not by the "end target" (whatever that is) - or vice versa.

I wouldn't put this into production on anything important without a ream or so of analysis!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do such oscillator in an FPGA, because the gates in the FPGA are not independent from each other. The gates in FPGA are made by using look-up tables, so the outputs of seemingly unrelated signals can have "glitches", or fast high-low transitions, when some other signal (which is generated using the same look-up table) changes.

With FPGAs you need to use a design methodology called "synchronous design". In synchronous design you use flip-flops with a common clock. You design the input logic of the flip-flops so that at each clock edge the output of the flip flop is what you want. And all signals that must not have extra oscillations (glitches) must come directly from an output of some flip-flop.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However by cascading odd number of Not gates oscillation happens. However in required design it is not important for me to have a desired frequency or have stable signal without glitches. However I want to stop oscillation of NOT gates somehow without using clock from external sources.

Comment: You can stop the oscillation of that circuit by modifying the AND2 feedback gate. Another option is to put another AND2 gate to the output to keep the output quiet even if the oscillator is ringing - make a binary counter from 4 toggle flip-flops to count from 0 to 15 and stop the oscillator or gate the output when the counter reaches "1111". Again, you *cannot* do this with FPGA. If you get an oscillation with an FPGA using this method, it's by chance, not by design and it's not reliable (unless you hand PAR the FPGA and know the properties of the FPGA macrocell implementation **exactly**)

Comment: @PkP That's actual not correct. There are people, who build noise sources and true random number generators on FPGAs by using LUTs in a loop, which oscillate. They instantiate primitives and wire them by hand. After that these primitives are placed by hand and protected by constraints, so that they are in a private area on the FPGA. Read more: http://liu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:305133/FULLTEXT01.pdf http://www.chesworkshop.org/ches2011/presentations/Session%201/CHES2011_Session1_2.pdf

Comment: @Paebbels, I *did* mention you can do that if you know the FPGA and place and route the fpga by hand.