# Digital Frequency tripler design

Tags: digital-logic, frequency, boolean-algebra

How can I implement a digital circuit using boolean logic gates?
[image]
As you see, on each rising edge, an oscillation happens and signal returns back to HIGH logic level after oscillation. This is also the same for falling edge.

Comment: Do you have a clock signal in your design? What is the frequency of the clock compared to the input?

Comment: No, I have no clock signal. Input signal of this circuit, is output of a pure combinational logic circuit. Transitions happen due to change in inputs of combinational source circuit.

Comment: Are you allowed to use reactive components or must everything be totally digital?

Comment: I think this is related to his other question - http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/150209/oscilator-with-limited-oscillation-count - maybe another problem for the same course? If it's for a course?

Comment: @pkp I want to use result of each question in the same task however they are different questions with different details.

Comment: VSB, Ok, so can you say can you use discrete components such as resistors and capacitors or do you need to do it all in silicon?

Answer (score 7):

Try creating two new signal with a delay RC circuit and a schmitt trigger: -

[image]

Then use exclusive OR gates on the three signals to create your desired output signal.

Comment: Hmm.. I don't think you're answering exactly his question.. he *did* ask how to do this with (only?) logic gates and his other question (http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/150209/oscilator-with-limited-oscillation-count) leads me to believe he's taking a digital microelectronic circuit elements course of some kind. A nice answer for a generic question, though, and, well, actually, to a degree propagation delays of microelectronic circuits *could* be seen as RC delays.

Comment: I did post desired answer.

Comment: @PkP - it's a difficult one this because the word "only" could be taken to exclude power supplies and decoupling capacitors. OK I'm pushing that a bit here but i would also point out that the delay of a logic element is primarily due to charging capacitors thru limited current devices and this is very akin to resistor-capacitor elements. Aha I see that you said this above.

Answer (score 2):

If this is purely asynchronous design as you say, then you need to generate timing signals of your own. If this is a university studies question, then the expected answer is proabably to use the propagation delays of independent gates to drive signals up and down; connect several gates (such as inverters) after each other to make signals with different propagation delays. Then use independent logic gates to combine the delayed signals into the output waveform which you need. This techniques is possible with full-custom IC design or by using separate logic gates (such as 74HCxxx series logic ICs). But this design methodology is not possible with FPGAs because FPGAs don't have separate gates. (Unless you place-and-route the FPGA by hand using gates from hand-picked macrocells whose properties you know.)

Other design methods call for *making* a clock signal, by using some kind of oscillator. Then you can use that clock signal to make a synchronous design which can be implemented by any design methodology of your choice, such as FPGAs. (I am mentioning FPGAs because you talk about them in another question of yours).

Answer (score 0):

I did implement circuit sktechd in schematic below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJnHkL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Implementing it in Verilog and simulating it on Xilinx ISE considering gate delays leads to below result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So basically you did as I suggested?

Comment: Yes, however I guess practical result in FIELD will be much better, since I think delay of Switch-boxes and wires are not monitored in simulation completely.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just remember that if you implement this in FPGA, it may or may not work like this, depending on how the gates are mapped. Normally the logic optimizer removes those inverters ("NOT" ports) and you'll end up with "a xor a xor a" which is **a** so the XOR will also be optimized away and the output will be directly connected to the input (no logic produced).

Comment: I did add `(* KEEP = "TRUE" *)` to INV gates to avoid them removing during synthesis.